# Why doesn't my backgound image work in CSS when the image name has a hyphen in it?

Tags: php, html, css

When image names have a hyphen in them, they do not load. When the hyphen is removed, they work fine.

Does anyone know why this is happening? There are lots of images with hyphens, so I want to know how can I fix this without having to rename all the image names.

Here is the sample of the code:

```
background:url(../img/new-jb-hvr.jpg);
```

Some may suggest to use `""` but it does not work when in IE.

This also does not work:

```
background:url("../img/new-jb-hvr.jpg");
```

The path is correct.

It works well in HTML. The problem is when the code is in PHP.

Comment: Please post the *exact* php code you're using.

Comment: He needs to post the HTML code that is sent to the browser. What happens in the PHP code is irrelevant since the browser doesn't know about it.

Comment: Post your PHP code, i think you may add backslash before ", EX: echo "background:url(\"./img/new.jpg\");";

Comment: The browser don't know about php code, but may be his php code produce some specific behavour, and this cause wrong HTML result.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for what you need? It takes away the hyphens.

```
<?php

$badBackground = "background:url(../img/new-jb-hvr.jpg);"
$goodBackground = str_replace('-', '', $badBackground );

echo $goodBackground;

?>
```

Comment: this is not a good option since you can not use php script in CSS file